# Google Firebase Functions deployment fails - what can I do?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Error message:

```
Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

firebease-debug.log holds this:

```
 [debug] [2021-11-16T12:12:16.165Z] Error: Failed to upsert schedule function lab2 in region europe-west3
```

function code:

```
exports.lab2 =
    functions
        .region('europe-west3')
        .pubsub.schedule('*/10 * * * *')
        .onRun(lab);
```

What can I do? Google support leads to stackoverflow, so I post it here. Are there better ways to deal with the Google Cloud problems?

Comment: When you are using scheduled functions in Firebase Functions, an App Engine instance is created that is needed for Cloud Scheduler to work. You can read about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).They use the location that has been set by default for resources. I think that you are getting that error because there is a difference between the default GCP resource location you specified and the region of your scheduled cloud function. If you click on the cogwheel next to project-overview in Firebase you can see where your resources are located.

Comment: Also how did you contact Google Cloud Support? If there is a public issue created on your behalf on this, kindly share the issue link here.

Comment: thank you, the default ressource location is unset, i initiated it to be set. sounds like a very good hint - will report the result.

Comment: after setting the default ressource location, deployment works fine now. thx so much. google should improve the error messages in firebase + cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using scheduled functions in Firebase Functions, an App Engine instance is created that is needed for Cloud Scheduler to work. You can read about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). During its setup you're prompted to select your project's default Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resource location (if it wasn't already selected when setting up another service).

You are getting that error because there is a difference between the default GCP resource location you specified and the region of your scheduled Cloud Function. If you click on the cogwheel next to project-overview in Firebase you can see where your resources are located. Setting the default GCP resource location same as the scheduler function region, solves the issue.

Comment: I'm running into same error but issue isn't related to region. Locally with my credentials firebase deploy works.  In CI with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS firebase deploy fails with  Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts/docker/xxxx/us-central1/gcf-artifacts
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to upsert schedule function maintenanceBackupDaily in region us-central1

Comment: @LeblancMeneses I have the same issue. I can't find any solution either.

Comment: Ok people, I have struggled for the entire Sunday with this and it turns out it was just a lack of attention, I will try to help you. Probably you are doing the Cron String wrongly, I don´t know why but the generator I have used, had 7 characters however, the Unix Cron Format The GCP accepts has only 5. So just check out this documentation:

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules?hl=pt&_ga=2.106943555.-1372726183.1644271382&_gac=1.225018472.1646428357.CjwKCAiAjoeRBhAJEiwAYY3nDNBVhiSk0D_xzPH1kv30gVU_PMzjhovy-m-6K66OogYA86NyoYkRMRoCHnIQAvD_BwE#defining_the_job_schedule

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason our schedule function deployment failed was because of the cron job formula. For some reason firebase couldn't understand `0 0 3 1/1 * ? *`, but could understand `every 5 minutes`.

It's a shame that firebase doesn't provide a better error message. `Error: Failed to upsert schedule function xxx in region xxx` is way too generic.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem of deploying my schedule functions, and I solved it with a few steps as below:

- Step 1: Rename the schedule function (for example: newScheduleABC), then only deploy it:

> $ Firebase deploy --only functions:newScheduleABC

NOTE: as @Nicholas mentioned, the Unix Cron Format The GCP accepts has only 5 fields: schedule(* * * * *)

- Step 2: Delete old (schedule) functions by going to your Firebase Console : https://console.firebase.google.com/.../functions , you will see all of your functions there. click on the vertical ellipsis at the end of a function and click delete.

That's it. There should be no problem from now.

You can read more from [Manage functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify)